# How to replace the third comma in a csv file with a space in linux using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a file of a table, the columns of which were separated by spaces. I wrote the following bash script to convert the spaces to commas:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /home/foo/*; do
  i=`basename $f`
  i2=${i%.*}
  cut -f 1,2,3,4 < $f | tr -s [:blank:] ',' > $i2.csv
done
```

But I missed something that my datetime has a space between the date and time, and now there is a comma there. The datetime's comma is the third one, is there any way to replace the third comma for all the rows with a space in linux?

Comment: `sed 's/,/ /3'` maybe? I'm not sure what your input file really looks like.

Comment: @BenjaminW. It looks like this: `6000,0,2012-01-01,08:00:00,9,foo,x,0.123`
next rows would be the same just different data

Comment: @BenjaminW. Your solution worked perfectly, if you want to post it as a solution, i an accept it as the correct answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sed `s` command has a flag to specify which occurrence of a regex to apply the command to:

```
sed 's/,/ /3' infile
```

modifies the third `,` in each line and replaces it with a space.

Comment: @αғsнιη Quote from [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html): "*n*: Substitute for the *n*th occurrence only of the BRE found within the pattern space" So any sed for which this solution doesn't work is not POSIX conformant. I see it in the man pages for [BSD sed](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1) and [macOS sed](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

To work in all `sed` implementation you could use:

```
sed -r 's/^(([^,]*,){2}[^,]*),/\1 /' infile
```

Comment: The flag to replace a specific occurrence is specified by POSIX.